# Weird constructor called when I called a function in nowhere

Tags: c++, constructor

Do you explain what is this situation?

The constructor with parameter has called When I called foo(3) function which is not exist in class Test.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace MyNameSpace{
    class Test{

    public:
    Test(int a){
        cout << "Test constructor with parameter has called" << endl;
    }
    };
    }

int main() {

    MyNameSpace::Test foo(3);

    return 0;
}
```

result is

```
Test constructor with parameter has called
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question indicates unfamiliarity with basic C++ syntax.

Comment: I'm newbee of C++! Sorry for poor question :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just defining a `MyNameSpace::Test` instance named `foo` by calling its constructor `MyNameSpace::Test(int)`. This is called *direct initialization*:

```
MyNameSpace::Test foo(3); // direct initialization
```

The output is what would be expected.

Note that since C++11, this alternative syntax would have the same effect *in this particular case*<sup>1</sup>:

```
MyNameSpace::Test foo{3}; // direct initialization, C++11
```

Also, *copy initialization* has the same effect in this case. Technically, it has more requirements on a type than direct initialization<sup>2</sup>:

```
MyNameSpace::Test foo = 3; // copy initialization
```

---

<sup>1 But not if your class had a constructor taking an `std::initializer_list`. That constructor gets favoured when using curly-brace initialization.</sup>

<sup>2 The type needs an accessible *copy constructor*, although the copy itself is likely to be elided.</sup>

Comment: Alternative syntax being available in C++11 or later.

Comment: @juanchopanza: no, you did not. You wrote "since C++" and then you reverted the edit when it was fixed to c++11. :)

Comment: @LaszloPapp Yikes! You're right. I am still not awake. I meant C++11. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

foo is not a function, it is the name of object of your class.
when you do this:

```
Test foo(3); // you are creating an instance of your class
```

and parameterized  constructor is called

```
Test(int a){
        cout << "Test constructor with parameter has called" << endl;
    } // here is your parameterized constructor which takes int as argument
```

and in main you are sending argument 3 which is an int, so your parameterized constructor is called.

Answer (score 0):

This constructor is called:

```
Test(int a){
    cout << "Test constructor with parameter has called" << endl;
}
```

because you are constructing a `MyNameSpace::Test` class object with parameter 3 as an integer passed to the constructor.

```
MyNameSpace::Test foo(3);
```

This is not a function call as you seem to imagine. It would be incorrect even for function declaration, and a function call would be something like this anyhow:

```
foo(3);
```

C++11 introduced the uniform initialization syntax which should make it clearer for you as you would write it then like this:

```
MyNameSpace::Test foo{3};
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `Test foo(3)` is the C++ way of creating a object of type `Test` with the name `foo` on the stack, passing the argument `3` to it's constructor.